# How do I make a embed be edited after someone interact with the button

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I want to know how I can edit the embed that was sent before because of someone that interacted with the buttons of it.

Example:

```
[|Now Playing          ]
[|Music A              ]
[|Duration: 1:00       ]
[|Vol: 100%            ]
[Add 10 of volume] [Subtract 10 of volume] (buttons)
```

If user clicks the button of "Add 10 of volume", the bot would send the message that he added 10 to the volume and it will edit the embed to show the new porcentage of volume and the same thing with the "Subtract 10 of volume", but subtracting it by 10.

My code now:

```
const { MessageEmbed, MessageActionRow, MessageButton} = require("discord.js");
const { convertTime } = require('../../utils/convert.js');
    
module.exports = async (client, player, track, payload) => {
  const emojiplay = client.emoji.play;
  
  const thing = new MessageEmbed()
  .setTitle("Começou a tocar.")
    .setDescription(`${emojiplay} [${track.title}](${track.uri})`)
    .addField('Duração:',`${convertTime(track.duration)}`, false)
    .addField('vol')
    .setThumbnail(track.displayThumbnail("3"))
    .setColor(client.embedColor)
    .setTimestamp()
   const But1 = new MessageButton().setCustomId("vdown").setEmoji("").setStyle("SECONDARY").setLabel("-10 Vol.") ;
    
   const But2 = new MessageButton().setCustomId("stop").setEmoji("❌").setStyle("SECONDARY").setLabel("Finalizar sessão");

   const But3 = new MessageButton().setCustomId("pause").setEmoji("⏸").setStyle("SECONDARY").setLabel("Pausar/Reproduzir");

   const But4 = new MessageButton().setCustomId("skip").setEmoji("⏭️").setStyle("SECONDARY").setLabel("Pular");
    
   const But5 = new MessageButton().setCustomId("vup").setEmoji("").setStyle("SECONDARY").setLabel("+10 de Vol.");
   
   const row = new MessageActionRow().addComponents(But1, But2, But3, But4, But5);
   
  let NowPlaying = await client.channels.cache
    .get(player.textChannel)
    .send({ embeds: [thing], components: [row] });
  player.setNowplayingMessage(NowPlaying);
  
  const collector = NowPlaying.createMessageComponentCollector({
    filter: (b) => {
      if(b.guild.me.voice.channel && b.guild.me.voice.channelId === b.member.voice.channelId) return true;
      else {
        b.reply({content: `You are not connected to ${b.guild.me.voice.channel} to use this buttons.`, ephemeral: true}); return false;
        };
     },
     time: track.duration,
      });
        collector.on("collect", async (i) => {
            if (i.customId === "vdown") {
               if (!player) {
                 return collector.stop();
               }
              let amount = Number(player.volume) - 10;
               await player.setVolume(amount);
              i.reply({content: `Volume set to ${amount} `, ephemeral: true});
           } else if (i.customId === "stop") {
                if (!player) {
                    return collector.stop();
                }
                await player.stop();
                await player.queue.clear();
                i.reply({content: "Music Is Stopped", ephemeral: true});
                return collector.stop();
            } else if (i.customId === "pause") {
                if (!player) {
                    return collector.stop();
                }
                player.pause(!player.paused);
                const Text = player.paused ? "paused" : "resume";
                i.reply({content: `I have ${Text} the music!`, ephemeral: true});
            } else if (i.customId === "skip") {
                if (!player) {
                    return collector.stop();
                }
                await player.stop();
                i.reply({content: "I have skipped to the next song!", ephemeral: true});
                if (track.length === 1) {
                    return collector.stop();
                }
            } else if (i.customId === "vup") {
               if (!player) {
                 return collector.stop();
               }
               let amount = Number(player.volume) + 10;
            if(amount >= 150) return i.reply({ content: `Cannot higher the player volume further more.`, ephemeral: true });
               await player.setVolume(amount);
               
               i.reply({content: `Volume set to ${amount} `, ephemeral: true});
                return;
            }
      });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly, you cannot edit embeds, so to do that, your bot will need to recreate an embed with the right parameters, then to `message.edit({embeds: [theNewEmbed]})`. I advise you to code a function that returns this embed depending of some parameters to avoid bloating your code with embed creations.

Comment: And it's possible to delete the old embed?

Comment: When doing `{embeds: [newEmbed]}`, it will automatically delete the embed

Comment: Also, you *can* access the original embed using `message.embeds[0]`